# Change Range of Numbers to be Negative in VBA

Tags: excel, range, negative-number, vba

I am trying to program a macro in excel. Ideally, I would select a group of cells with numbers and press a key and these numbers would all become negative. This would save me a great deal of time and I would appreciate a solution.

Comment: type -1 into a cell, copy it, select the range you want to update, then Paste Multiply.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Even though your problem is quite easy to solve using VBA -or maybe a formula, this is not a place providing ready-to-consume code service. For a good start, I would recommend you to search for "Excel macro recording" on the net and come back here for help when you stuck at a point in that context.

Comment: Are any of the existing numbers negative?  Do any of the cells contain formulas?

Comment: `selection.numberformat = "-general"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub Negativize()
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In Selection
        cel.Value = -Abs(cel.Value)
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code for a selection :

```
Sub negative()

    Dim cel As Range
    Dim selectedRange As Range

    Set selectedRange = Application.Selection

    For Each cel In selectedRange.Cells
        If cel.Value > 0 Then
        cel.Value = cel.Value - (cel.Value * 2)
        End If
    Next cel

End Sub
```

Or this for one cell :

```
Sub negative()
if ActiveCell.Value > 0 then
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value - (ActiveCell.Value * 2)
end if

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Make_Selection_Negative()
    Dim cell As Object

    For Each cell In Selection
        cell = cell - cell - cell
    Next cell

End Sub
```